# How prove the inequality $AB+AC+AD+AE \leq 4\sqrt{2}R$ for 5 points on a sphere with radius R?

Tags: geometry

$A,B,C,D,E$ are 5 points on a sphere with radius R 
such that $\angle{BAC}=\angle{CAD}=\angle{DAE}=\angle{EAB}=\frac{2}{3}\angle{BAD}=\frac{2}{3}\angle{CAE}$.

How prove the inequality $AB+AC+AD+AE \leq 4\sqrt{2}R$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the first four angles are equal, $BCDE$ is a square. Since $\widehat{BAD}=\frac{3}{2}\widehat{BAC}$, the plane $\pi$ where $BCDE$ lies must be close enough to $A$, in particular the amplitude of the angle $\widehat{AOD}$ (where $O$ is the center of the sphere) cannot exceed $\frac{\pi}{2}$, from which the claim follows.

Comment: Can you explain why $BCDE$ is a square? In fact, I don't even see that they are coplanar.

Comment: Consider the plane through $B$ and $C$ that is orthogonal to the $OA$-line. Then $B,C,D,E$ all belong to this plane and to the intersection between this plane and the sphere, the circle $\Gamma$ with center $O'$. All the angles like $\widehat{BO'C}$ are equal, hence $BCDE$ is a square.

Comment: Nope, don't see it. The way I imagine is that there's a solid symmetrical angle at $A$. If I put the center $O$ outside of the symmetry axis, then $B,C,D,E$ are not coplanar.